# Why do I get an out of range in C++ but not in Perl?

Tags: c++, perl

I want to calculate an even distribution of tasks across *n* workers. A task consist of a pairwise comparison; each of *m* items is compared to itself and the others. I want to avoid redundant comparisons.

For example, for 4 items and 3 workers that would be (4 + 3 + 2 + 1 = 10) tasks, which would be distributed across 3 workers. Each worker gets a maximum of `ceil(10/3)` tasks. They are distributed as follows. I generate a *m***m* matrix and take the lower (diagonally-separated) half of it, like this:

```
  1 2 3 4
1 x - - -
2 x x - -
3 x x x -
4 x x x x
```

And I walk the matrix, assigning tasks to workers up to their maximum, at which point the next worker gets the tasks.

I implemented this in Perl, which works well:

```
my $total  = 0;
for (my $i = 0; $i < $nitems; $i++) {
    for (my $j = 0; $j <= $i; $j++) { $total++ }
}
my $tasksperworker = ceil($total / $nworkers);

my $worker = [  ];
push @$worker, { 'imin' => 1, 'imax' => 1, 'jmin' => 1, 'jmax' => 1 } for (1 .. $nworkers);
my $k = 0;

for (my $i = 0; $i < $nitems; $i++) {
    for (my $j = 0; $j <= $i; $j++) {
        # start a new worker if this one would be overloaded
        if ($tasksforthisworker + 1 > $tasksperworker) {
            $k++;

            $$worker[$k]{'imin'} = $i;
            $$worker[$k]{'imax'} = $i;
            $$worker[$k]{'jmin'} = $j;
            $$worker[$k]{'jmax'} = $j;

            $tasksforthisworker = 1;
        }

        else {
            $$worker[$k]{'imin'} = $i if $$worker[$k]{'imin'} > $i;
            $$worker[$k]{'imax'} = $i if $$worker[$k]{'imax'} < $i;
            $$worker[$k]{'jmin'} = $j if $$worker[$k]{'jmin'} > $j;
            $$worker[$k]{'jmax'} = $j if $$worker[$k]{'jmax'} < $j;

            $tasksforthisworker++;
        }
    }
}
```

I need to compute this for larger values of *m*,  though. The Perl version has been calculating all weekend for input values of *n* = 8 and *m* = 1397704. I realize that this results in an abhorrently large number of tasks, but they need to be done nonetheless. So the Perl version is still processing and I want to implement the thing in C++ for efficiency. I think I got the algorithm copied here:

```
// populate the workers array
vector <map <string, int> > workers (nworkers);
for (int i = 0; i < nworkers; i++) {
    map <string, int> worker;
    worker["imin"] = 1;
    worker["imax"] = 1;
    worker["jmin"] = 1;
    worker["jmax"] = 1;
    workers[i] = worker;
}

// calculate total number of tasks and tasks per worker
int total = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < nitems; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) total++;
}
int tasksperworker = ceil( total / nworkers );


// distribute tasks across workers
int tasksforthisworker = 0;
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int k = 0;
for (i = 0; i < nitems; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
        // start a new worker if this one would be overloaded
        if (tasksforthisworker + 1 > tasksperworker) {
            // this would exceed the number of workers!
            assert(k + 1 > workers.size());
            k++;
            workers.at(k)["imin"] = i;
            workers.at(k)["imax"] = i;
            workers.at(k)["jmin"] = j;
            workers.at(k)["jmax"] = j;
            tasksforthisworker = 1;
        }
        else {
            if (workers.at(k)["imin"] > i) workers.at(k)["imin"] = i;
            if (workers.at(k)["imax"] < i) workers.at(k)["imax"] = i;
            if (workers.at(k)["jmin"] > j) workers.at(k)["jmin"] = j;
            if (workers.at(k)["jmax"] < j) workers.at(k)["jmax"] = j;
            tasksforthisworker++;
        }
    }
}
```

This gives me an error because `k` is exceeding `workers.size()` at some point:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  vector::_M_range_check
```

The `assert()` marks the point where the error occurs.

My question is this: Why does this happen in the C++ version while it doesn't in the Perl version? Am I missing something in the C++ implementation (which may well be)?

Pointers for more efficient calculation of this task distribution are also appreciated. This algorithm was the first that sprang to my mind when I was thinking about the problem.

Comment: A std::vector::operator [] does not reserve space for an element, it only references one (In your case a non existing element) You may replace `workers[i] = worker;` with `workers.push_back(worker);`

Comment: For m=4, the number of comparisons needed by your approach is `3+2+1=6`, not `4+3+2+1=10` (and definitely not `4+3+2+1=15`?!) `1+2+3+4+...+x = x(x+1)/2`, so your approaches requires `(m-1)m/2` comparisons. That's in the order of `m*m`. Sorting m elements requires far fewer comparisons (in the order of `m*log(m)`). Why don't you sort the elements?

Comment: @ikegami: you are right, I had the example for 5 items and 4 workers before I decided to make it simpler. The 15 and 4 are remnants from that older version. Sorry for the confusion! However, it's still 4+3+2+1=10 since each item needs to be compared to itself.

Comment: @DieterLücking: thanks for the suggestion! Will do that.

Comment: @mpe, It makes no sense to compare something against itself. You already know its the same. I'm suprised you focused on that rather than the fact that I provided a far faster algorithm!

Comment: @ikegami: It does in this case, since the comparison is a self-alignment of a sequence of characters, where local similarities may be found in different locations across the sequence. This is not a sorting algorithm, but you are right, I might find more efficiency looking in that direction. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: To the downvoter: Would you care to explain your downvote?

Comment: Although we've implemented an on-line tax bill payment and a water billing system in Perl, there are fix-ups you have to do. One area is rounding when doing arithmetic with decimals. Perl is notorious for not getting floats correct. You'll have to algorithm-ize rounding, which we do.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus: If you are the downvoter: Of course, Perl is not the best for floating-point arithmetics, but this isn't a calculation that needs precision down to the nth. I don't think this issue merits a downvote. Our views on this may differ.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus, Re "Perl is notorious for not getting floats correct." That's completely false you mean: Floats (in any language) are notorious for not getting numbers correct. e.g. 1/3, 1/5, 1/6, 1/7, 1/9, 1/10 are all periodic numbers in binary, so none of them can be accurately represented by a float.

Comment: I didn't downvote the question. I added my expereience with Perl.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus: Thanks for that. You're right, floats shouldn't be trusted unless dealt with specifically (and correctly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are 2 problems:

1. you are calling ceil on the result of integer arithmetic, which is already a floor, so you're actually getting the result of ceil(floor(x/y)). Change the line to read:

   ```
   // Ceiling of total divided by nworkers
   int tasksperworker = (total + nworkers - 1)/ nworkers;
   ```
2. the inequality in your assertion should be < :

   ```
   assert(k + 1 < workers.size());
   ```

Then it'll work.

fun (but irrelevant) fact: you can make it more perl-like by using std::generate_n for the vector initialisation:

```
    vector <map <string, int> > workers (nworkers);
    std::generate_n(back_inserter(workers), nworkers, []{
        return std::map<string, int>{
            { "imin", 1 },
            { "imax", 1 },
            { "jmin", 1 },
            { "jmax", 1 },
        };});
```

Comment: You are right, this fixes the problem. I was confused about the C++ version's `tasksperworkers` being offset by 1, that is explained by your answer. I didn't realize that integer division is floored by default. Thank you!

Comment: it's a consequence of c++ being strongly typed. The result of the division of two integers is an integer. The digits after the decimal point are simply dropped, resulting in what is essentially a floor.
your code would have worked had it been written: `int tasksperworker = ceil(double(total) / double(nworkers));` since the result of dividing a double by a double is a double.

Comment: Right. I knew this. Silly me! Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

You are incrementing `k` before accessing any elements of `workers`. This means that the element of `workers` with the index 0 will never be accessed, and you are probably trying to access the element with the index `workers.size()` at some point. The last element which can be accessed has the index `workers.size() - 1`. While Perl seems to expand arrays on demand, acessing elements of an array or vector in C++ will lead to errors, and accessing with `.at()` will produce an exception.

Comment: Note that C++ doesn't have to "throw an error" in general. It only happens if you use the `at` element access members.

Comment: @juanchopanza I might have expressed myself a bit sloppy, can you give me a better expression?

Comment: In C++, it *is* an error to access an array out of bounds, but the behaviour of a program that does that is *undefined*. No error needs to be thrown, but anything can happen. The same applies to `std::vector`, unless the element is accessed via the `at()` method, in which case you get an `std::out_of_range` exception.

Comment: @juanchopanza I got it. Actually, if you debug in MSVC, an exception will be thrown if you try to access elements of an array beyond its bounds, this is why I never noticed that there will usually be no immediate error message in this case. Thank you for explaining.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but as far as I read it, I am assigning assigning tasks to `workers[0]` until it is "full" (`tasksforthisworker + 1 > tasksperworker`) before incrementing `k`.